# Wordpress / OceanWP -> disable add to cart button if 2 conditions are met

Tags: php, wordpress

When a product is out of my stock **AND** out of my supplier's stock, I'd like to disable the add to cart button.
My code in functions.php :

```
    function remove_addcart() {
   global $post;
    if (is_product()) {
    $product = wc_get_product($post->ID);
    $dispo = $product->get_attribute( 'pa_disponibilite' );
    if (($dispo != 1) && (($product->stock) == 0)) {
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', '__return_false');
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'wp', 'remove_addcart' );
```

It works, except on archive, search and category page, due to OceanWP theme.
How can I get around this problem ?

See in action : https://www.leslibrairesvoyageurs.fr/sitetest/ :

5th book is no longer available, product page is ok, without add to cart button (https://www.leslibrairesvoyageurs.fr/sitetest/produit/100-ans-dexploration-francaise/), but shop page still displays it...

Thanks for helping !

EDIT : Vinay Jain's solution doesn't work.
Replacing my function by

```
add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable','custom_non_purchasable_product', 10, 2 );
function custom_non_purchasable_product( $is_purchasable, $product ) {

    $dispo = $product->get_attribute( 'pa_disponibilite' );
    if (($dispo != 1) && (($product->stock) == 0)) {
        $is_purchasable = false;
    }
    return $is_purchasable;
}
```

does exactly the same. I think OceanWP theme doesn't like "$is_purchasable"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

```
add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable','custom_non_purchasable_product', 10, 2 );
    function custom_non_purchasable_product( $is_purchasable, $product ) {
        return (
            (1 != (int) $product->get_attribute( 'pa_disponibilite' )) &&
            (!is_null($product->get_stock_quantity())) &&
            ($product->get_stock_quantity() == 0)
        ) ? false : $is_purchasable;
    }
```

The above code finally worked for Autour.

**OLD ANSWER:**

A better approach would be to check when the product is loaded anywhere using the following code:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'modify_query_for_visibility' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'modify_query_for_visibility', 10, 2 );
function modify_query_for_visibility( $q ) {

    if ( ! $q->is_main_query() || is_admin() ) {
        return;
    }

    $postType = $q->get( 'post_type');
    if ('product' == $postType || 'product_variation' == $postType){
        
        $tax_query = (array) $q->get('tax_query');

        $tax_query[] = array(
            'taxonomy'        => 'pa_disponibilite',
            'field'           => 'slug',
            'terms'           =>  array(1),
            'operator'        => 'IN',
        );
    
        $q->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );

        remove_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'modify_query_for_visibility' );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'modify_query_for_visibility' );
    }
}

add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable','custom_non_purchasable_product', 10, 2 );
function custom_non_purchasable_product( $is_purchasable, $product ) {
    return (
        (1 != (int) $product->get_attribute( 'pa_disponibilite' )) &&
        (!is_null($product->get_stock_quantity())) &&
        ($product->get_stock_quantity() == 0)
    ) ? false : $is_purchasable;
}
```

This code will execute whenever a product loads at any place in any theme or plugin.

Comment: I've updated my answer, can you try that once? It'll possibly work.

Comment: ```
add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable','custom_non_purchasable_product', 999, 2 );
function custom_non_purchasable_product( $is_purchasable, $product ) {

    if (($product->get_attribute( 'pa_disponibilite' ) != 1) && ($product->get_stock_quantity() == 0)) {
        $is_purchasable = false;
    }
    return $is_purchasable;
}
```
Same, nothing changed...

Comment: Ok, hold on testing on my local

Comment: I updated my answer again. Please try that. I tried and it's working in the WP ocean theme as well as storefront theme on my local.

Comment: Still not working (look at www.leslibrairesvoyageurs.fr/sitetest) : Now, ONLY "non sellables" books appears on the shop, and ALWAYS with a "add to cart" button...

Comment: Are you sure you have an attribute disponibilite added under attributes and one of its values is 1?

Comment: Come on chat here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247563/chat-with-autour-du-monde

Comment: Yes. Attribute pa_disponibilite : if value is 1, it is available with my supplier, otherwise, I cannot order it

Comment: I cannot enter the chat because of : You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here... My @ is contact@leslibrairesvoyageurs.fr